# when click notification, if app was in background, android create new instance

Tags: android, notifications, background

I have a application. if my app was in background and receive notification, when click on notification, new instance of app launch and when this new instance finished, first instance come foreground and launch from last activity.
I want when click on notification my app restart and first instance finish.

Comment: Have you tried flags in notification intent? (like ```notificationIntent.addFlags(
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);```)

Comment: @Kamal if app was in background, then not run resume program and onMessagereceived() not work. then app start normally and when finish app, then background app resume.